# Set style on ComboBoxItem from template for ComboBox

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, templates

I am doing a template for some ComboBox controls in WPF. But I want to also style the ComboBoxItems from within this template. I've only found how to apply a Style from where the control is created, but not from within the template of the ComboBox.

The template I am working with is taken from here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752094.aspx

But the ComboBoxItem style (found at the bottom) there is applied to ALL ComboBoxItems (due to `x:Key="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}"`.

Comment: Do you want to only apply your style to the `ComboBoxItems` of a specific `ComboBox`?

Comment: I want to apply it to all children of a combobox with a certain style.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should swap the style definition of the msdn sample

```
<Style x:Key="{x:Type ComboBox}"
       TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
```

with the following one

```
<Style x:Key="MyComboBox" TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
```

then explicitly assign the style to your comboboxes in the following way

```
<ComboBox Style="{StaticResource MyComboBox}" />
```

[x:Key Directive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742804.aspx)

> The attribute value of x:Key can be any string defined in the XamlName
>   Grammar or can be an object evaluated through a markup extension.

The way the style is defined in msdn sample illustrates how to override the default style for comboboxes, to explicitly specify a style use a string instead of the markup extension to specify the style in ComboBox Resources.

EDIT

The same should be done for ComboBoxItems style so swap the code

```
<Style x:Key="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}" TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}">
```

with the code

```
<Style x:Key="MyComboBox" TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
```

and also add in the code for the ComboBox style the following directive

```
<Setter Property="ItemContainerStyle" Value="{StaticResource MyComboxItem}"/>
```

here is a brief example of how to have the styled combo box and another one with the default style in the same window.

XAML

```
<Window x:Class="WpfComboTemplate.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:coll="clr-namespace:System.Collections.ObjectModel;assembly=System"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <!--Control colors.-->
        <Color x:Key="WindowColor">#FFE8EDF9</Color>
        <Color x:Key="ContentAreaColorLight">#FFC5CBF9</Color>
        <Color x:Key="ContentAreaColorDark">#FF7381F9</Color>

        <Color x:Key="DisabledControlLightColor">#FFE8EDF9</Color>
        <Color x:Key="DisabledControlDarkColor">#FFC5CBF9</Color>
        <Color x:Key="DisabledForegroundColor">#FF888888</Color>

        <Color x:Key="SelectedBackgroundColor">#FFC5CBF9</Color>
        <Color x:Key="SelectedUnfocusedColor">#FFDDDDDD</Color>

        <Color x:Key="ControlLightColor">White</Color>
        <Color x:Key="ControlMediumColor">#FF7381F9</Color>
        <Color x:Key="ControlDarkColor">#FF211AA9</Color>

        <Color x:Key="ControlMouseOverColor">#FF3843C4</Color>
        <Color x:Key="ControlPressedColor">#FF211AA9</Color>


        <Color x:Key="GlyphColor">#FF444444</Color>
        <Color x:Key="GlyphMouseOver">sc#1, 0.004391443, 0.002428215, 0.242281124</Color>

        <!--Border colors-->
        <Color x:Key="BorderLightColor">#FFCCCCCC</Color>
        <Color x:Key="BorderMediumColor">#FF888888</Color>
        <Color x:Key="BorderDarkColor">#FF444444</Color>

        <Color x:Key="PressedBorderLightColor">#FF888888</Color>
        <Color x:Key="PressedBorderDarkColor">#FF444444</Color>

        <Color x:Key="DisabledBorderLightColor">#FFAAAAAA</Color>
        <Color x:Key="DisabledBorderDarkColor">#FF888888</Color>

        <Color x:Key="DefaultBorderBrushDarkColor">Black</Color>

        <!--Control-specific resources.-->
        <Color x:Key="HeaderTopColor">#FFC5CBF9</Color>
        <Color x:Key="DatagridCurrentCellBorderColor">Black</Color>
        <Color x:Key="SliderTrackDarkColor">#FFC5CBF9</Color>

        <Color x:Key="NavButtonFrameColor">#FF3843C4</Color>

        <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="MenuPopupBrush"
                     EndPoint="0.5,1"
                     StartPoint="0.5,0">
            <GradientStop Color="{DynamicResource ControlLightColor}"
                Offset="0" />
            <GradientStop Color="{DynamicResource ControlMediumColor}"
                Offset="0.5" />
            <GradientStop Color="{DynamicResource ControlLightColor}"
                Offset="1" />
        </LinearGradientBrush>

        <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="ProgressBarIndicatorAnimatedFill"
                     StartPoint="0,0"
                     EndPoint="1,0">
            <LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                <GradientStopCollection>
                    <GradientStop Color="#000000FF"
                    Offset="0" />
                    <GradientStop Color="#600000FF"
                    Offset="0.4" />
                    <GradientStop Color="#600000FF"
                    Offset="0.6" />
                    <GradientStop Color="#000000FF"
                    Offset="1" />
                </GradientStopCollection>
            </LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
        </LinearGradientBrush>


        <ControlTemplate x:Key="ComboBoxToggleButton"
                 TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="20" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                        <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                        <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                            <Storyboard>
                                <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).
                (GradientBrush.GradientStops)[1].(GradientStop.Color)"
                                          Storyboard.TargetName="Border">
                                    <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                   Value="{StaticResource ControlMouseOverColor}" />
                                </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </VisualState>
                        <VisualState x:Name="Pressed" />
                        <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                            <Storyboard>
                                <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).
                (GradientBrush.GradientStops)[1].(GradientStop.Color)"
                                          Storyboard.TargetName="Border">
                                    <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                   Value="{StaticResource DisabledControlDarkColor}" />
                                </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Fill).
                (SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                                          Storyboard.TargetName="Arrow">
                                    <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                   Value="{StaticResource DisabledForegroundColor}" />
                                </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.BorderBrush).
                (GradientBrush.GradientStops)[1].(GradientStop.Color)"
                                          Storyboard.TargetName="Border">
                                    <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                   Value="{StaticResource DisabledBorderDarkColor}" />
                                </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </VisualState>
                    </VisualStateGroup>
                    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CheckStates">
                        <VisualState x:Name="Checked">
                            <Storyboard>
                                <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).
                (GradientBrush.GradientStops)[1].(GradientStop.Color)"
                                          Storyboard.TargetName="Border">
                                    <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                   Value="{StaticResource ControlPressedColor}" />
                                </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </VisualState>
                        <VisualState x:Name="Unchecked" />
                        <VisualState x:Name="Indeterminate" />
                    </VisualStateGroup>
                </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                <Border x:Name="Border"
            Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
            CornerRadius="2"
            BorderThickness="1">
                    <Border.BorderBrush>
                        <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0,1"
                             StartPoint="0,0">
                            <GradientStop Color="{DynamicResource BorderLightColor}"
                        Offset="0" />
                            <GradientStop Color="{DynamicResource BorderDarkColor}"
                        Offset="1" />
                        </LinearGradientBrush>
                    </Border.BorderBrush>
                    <Border.Background>

                        <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0"
                             EndPoint="0,1">
                            <LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                                <GradientStopCollection>
                                    <GradientStop Color="{DynamicResource ControlLightColor}" />
                                    <GradientStop Color="{DynamicResource ControlMediumColor}"
                            Offset="1.0" />
                                </GradientStopCollection>
                            </LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                        </LinearGradientBrush>

                    </Border.Background>
                </Border>
                <Border Grid.Column="0"
            CornerRadius="2,0,0,2"
            Margin="1" >
                    <Border.Background>
                        <SolidColorBrush Color="{DynamicResource ControlLightColor}"/>
                    </Border.Background>
                </Border>
                <Path x:Name="Arrow"
          Grid.Column="1"
          HorizontalAlignment="Center"
          VerticalAlignment="Center"
          Data="M 0 0 L 4 4 L 8 0 Z" >
                    <Path.Fill>
                        <SolidColorBrush Color="{DynamicResource GlyphColor}"/>
                    </Path.Fill>
                </Path>
            </Grid>
        </ControlTemplate>

        <ControlTemplate x:Key="ComboBoxTextBox"
                 TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
            <Border x:Name="PART_ContentHost"
          Focusable="False"
          Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" />
        </ControlTemplate>



        <Style x:Key="MyComboxItem"
       TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}">
            <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels"
          Value="true" />
            <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle"
          Value="true" />
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}">
                        <Border x:Name="Border"
                Padding="2"
                SnapsToDevicePixels="true"
                Background="Transparent">
                            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="SelectionStates">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Unselected" />
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Border"
                                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).
                    (SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                                                <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                         Value="{StaticResource SelectedBackgroundColor}" />
                                            </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="SelectedUnfocused">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Border"
                                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).
                    (SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                                                <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                         Value="{StaticResource SelectedUnfocusedColor}" />
                                            </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <ContentPresenter />
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>


        <Style x:Key="MyComboBox"
       TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
            <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels"
          Value="true" />
            <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle"
          Value="true" />
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility"
          Value="Auto" />
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility"
          Value="Auto" />
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll"
          Value="true" />
            <Setter Property="MinWidth"
          Value="120" />
            <Setter Property="MinHeight"
          Value="20" />
            <Setter Property="ItemContainerStyle" Value="{StaticResource MyComboxItem}"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
                        <Grid>
                            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                                    <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver" />
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="PART_EditableTextBox"
                                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextElement.Foreground).
                      (SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                                                <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                         Value="{StaticResource DisabledForegroundColor}" />
                                            </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="EditStates">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Editable">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)"
                                                 Storyboard.TargetName="PART_EditableTextBox">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                            Value="{x:Static Visibility.Visible}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames
                      Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)"
                                                 Storyboard.TargetName="ContentSite">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                            Value="{x:Static Visibility.Hidden}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Uneditable" />
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <ToggleButton x:Name="ToggleButton"
                        Template="{StaticResource ComboBoxToggleButton}"
                        Grid.Column="2"
                        Focusable="false"
                        ClickMode="Press"
                        IsChecked="{Binding IsDropDownOpen, Mode=TwoWay, 
              RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"/>
                            <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentSite"
                            IsHitTestVisible="False"
                            Content="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItem}"
                            ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItemTemplate}"
                            ContentTemplateSelector="{TemplateBinding ItemTemplateSelector}"
                            Margin="3,3,23,3"
                            VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                            </ContentPresenter>
                            <TextBox x:Name="PART_EditableTextBox"
                   Style="{x:Null}"
                   Template="{StaticResource ComboBoxTextBox}"
                   HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                   VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                   Margin="3,3,23,3"
                   Focusable="True"
                   Background="Transparent"
                   Visibility="Hidden"
                   IsReadOnly="{TemplateBinding IsReadOnly}" />
                            <Popup x:Name="Popup"
                 Placement="Bottom"
                 IsOpen="{TemplateBinding IsDropDownOpen}"
                 AllowsTransparency="True"
                 Focusable="False"
                 PopupAnimation="Slide">
                                <Grid x:Name="DropDown"
                  SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
                  MinWidth="{TemplateBinding ActualWidth}"
                  MaxHeight="{TemplateBinding MaxDropDownHeight}">
                                    <Border x:Name="DropDownBorder"
                      BorderThickness="1">
                                        <Border.BorderBrush>
                                            <SolidColorBrush Color="{DynamicResource BorderMediumColor}" />
                                        </Border.BorderBrush>
                                        <Border.Background>
                                            <SolidColorBrush Color="{DynamicResource ControlLightColor}" />
                                        </Border.Background>
                                    </Border>
                                    <ScrollViewer Margin="4,6,4,6"
                            SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                                        <StackPanel IsItemsHost="True"
                            KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Contained" />
                                    </ScrollViewer>
                                </Grid>
                            </Popup>
                        </Grid>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="HasItems"
                   Value="false">
                                <Setter TargetName="DropDownBorder"
                    Property="MinHeight"
                    Value="95" />
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsGrouping"
                   Value="true">
                                <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll"
                    Value="false" />
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger SourceName="Popup"
                   Property="AllowsTransparency"
                   Value="true">
                                <Setter TargetName="DropDownBorder"
                    Property="CornerRadius"
                    Value="4" />
                                <Setter TargetName="DropDownBorder"
                    Property="Margin"
                    Value="0,2,0,0" />
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <ComboBox VerticalAlignment="Top"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding}">

        </ComboBox>
        <ComboBox VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                  Grid.Row="1" 
                  Style="{StaticResource MyComboBox}" 
                  ItemsSource="{Binding}">

        </ComboBox>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

C# Behind

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace WpfComboTemplate
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Logica di interazione per MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = new ObservableCollection<string>() {"Hello", "ComboBox"};
        }
    }
}
```

A sceenshot with the combobox using the default style
[image: Default ComboBox]

A sceenshot with styled combobox
[image: Styled ComboBox]

Comment: I know how to make style not apply everywhere. The key here is that I want to make it so that whenever the ComboBox style is used, the items gets the ComboBoxItem style applied.

Comment: I just edited my answer with the further actions to do to achieve your objective. To have styled comboboxes with different itemstyle you should define a new combox style for each combination.